# Exclude properties for migrations

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have *properties* on my model that I don't want to generate fields in the **tables** after a migration.

Is it possible to exclude *properties* for Entity Framework Core migrations?

Is there an attribute for the model or some Fluent API method on my `DbContext` for this?

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2725

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties or take a look at JsonIgnore attribute from Newtonsoft.Json...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to specify `[NotMapped]` as a data annotation above the property.

E.g. if you wanted to have `FullName` in your model which consisted of `FirstName` and `LastName` you would do:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string FullName { get;set };
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Ignore` method is usd to specify that the auto-implemented `FullName` property in the `Contact` class below is excluded from mapping:

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().Ignore(c => c.FullName);
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    public string Email { get; set; } 
}
```

**Note**: Data Annotations equivalent to the Ignore method is the `NotMapped` attribute.